# Remove a certain string from SELECT query sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A as shown below:

```
    File
  _________
   abc.pdf 
   def.pdf
   ghi.pdf
```

I want to make a query that brings back the results below:

```
   abc
   def
   ghi
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: are they always `.pdf` extensions? or 3 characters?

Comment: It will always be .pdf

Comment: Are all file names the character + extension? If not, adjust the sample data and the result.

Comment: Will always be character(s) + extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql server you can simply do:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Filename,'.pdf','') FROM File
```

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

**Update**
To prevent accidental removal of ".pdf" inside the filename is better to use

```
SELECT LEFT(Filename, LEN(Filename)-4) FROM File
```

that remove always the last 4 characters (`.pdf`)

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Try Below :

```
SELECT LEFT(data, CHARINDEX('.', data) - 1)
```

Or

If you have always '.pdf', then Just Use `Replace()` function :

```
select replace(data, '.pdf', '')
```

**Result :**

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below one to remove any extension, dynamic way to replace any extension in SQL

```
select LEFT(Filename,CHARINDEX('.', Filename) - 1) FROM File
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col1, 1, INSTR(col1, '.')-1) AS FileName from File
```

This will provide you the result in dynamic way.